# Complex matrix decomposition

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition

If I have a block matrix of complex matrices

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
P  &Q\\
Q^T & P
\end{bmatrix}
$$ 
while Q being skew symmetric, the decomposition is 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
I  & -iI\\
. & I
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
P-iQ  & .\\
-Q & I
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
I  & iI\\
. & P+iQ
\end{bmatrix}
$$
These are results from (R.A Wooding 1956).  Can anyone please explain what kind of complex decomposition is this or please provide any reference explaing this above decomposition. I have looked into [Block LU decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_LU_decomposition) but this does not explain how the above stated decomposition is working.

Appreciate your suggestions
!

Comment: Hi. What's the dot supposed to mean?

Comment: I think thats just dont care symbol

Comment: Ah, ok I assumed it was 0. I should add that to the hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: the matrix valued function of a scalar $a$ : $$m(a) = \left[\begin{array}{cc}1&0\\a&1\end{array}\right]$$ has the property that $$m(a)\cdot m(b) = m(a+b)$$
and this property carries over to block form with $\bf I$ corresponding to $1$ and $\bf 0$ corresponding to $0$:
$$m({\bf A}) = \left[\begin{array}{cc}\bf I&\bf 0\\{\bf A}&{\bf I}\end{array}\right]$$
so that:
$$m({\bf A})m({\bf B}) = m({\bf A+B})$$

Hopefully this can help you gain some understanding.

Comment: Hi, Thank for your answer, I am wondering how does this hint relates to the decomposition problem in question. Please explain a bit more. Thanks

Comment: Maybe reading about Schur Complements can help you. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement

Comment: Thats really helpful, What do you think about the matrix in the middle, it contains a -Q at the off diagonal. From where this -Q come from whereas LDU decomposition formula have zeros in the off diagonal entries?

Comment: Maybe the $i$ are used to make it cancel somehow thanks to $i^2=-1$, I don't know. Why don't you try evaluate the multiplication.

Comment: I evaluated the multiplication it gives me this $$\begin{pmatrix}
P &i P-i P+Q\\
-Q& -iQ+P+iQ
\end{pmatrix}
$$
As we know from the paper Q=-Q' and P=P' then matrix can be written as
$$\begin{pmatrix}
P & Q\\
Q'& P
\end{pmatrix}
$$ So thats the exact answer by multiplication. The thing is just that I want to understand how its decomposed and by working out the Schur it is somewhat close but not exact decomposition, looks like there's a glitch.

Comment: As we know from **the paper**? No really I don't. Please enlighten me. Which paper? I think that - sign may come from twice multiplication by $i$ somewhere doesn't it? Something that would have been difficult to do with real numbers.

Comment: Its 'The Multivariate distribution of complex normal variables by R.A Wooding (1956)'. What I think is that Schur complement might be formulated as 
$$\begin{pmatrix}
I & BD^{-1}\\
0& I
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
A-BD^{-1}C & 0\\
-B & I
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
I & D^{-1}C\\
0 & A+BD^{-1}C
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Again like you said twice multiplication by $i$ should be cause of -Q but still that -B in second matrix should not exist it should be zero. There is not reference explaining this too, perhaps this is some trivial case.